# INSERT EN UNA TABLA A PARTIR DE OTRAS DOS EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Hola soy nuevo en MySQL y estoy atorado en un problema. Tengo **2 archivos Excel** y cada uno lo guardo en **2 tablas temporales**. El primer Excel viene una lista de los tags (temporal_tags) que necesitare para el segundo Excel en el que vienen datos (temporal_datos) por cada tag pero sin titulo porque tengo que agarrarlos del primer Excel. En cualquier momento pueden venir una cantidad mayor de tags así que hice la tabla temporal de datos con muchas columnas por las dudas.

```
temporal_tags:
id   tag
-----------
1    tag1
2    tag2
3    tag3


temporal_datos:
temp1    temp2    temp3    temp4    temp5
-----------------------------------------
a1       b1       c1       null     null
a2       b2       c2       null     null
a3       b3       c3       null     null
```

En este caso sólo vino el Excel de tags con 3 tags, así que el Excel de datos vino con datos en las primeras 3 columnas respectivamente. Necesito crear una **tercer tabla** en la pueda unir el id del tag con sus respectivos datos. Tendría que quedar así:

```
tabla_3:
id_tag    dato
--------------
1         a1
1         a2
1         a3
2         b1
2         b2
2         b3
3         c1
3         c2
3         c3
```

Comment: en tu tabla no tienes nada como relacionar, por nada, como sabes que registro pertenece a que columna

Comment: Se supone que cada registro de temp_tags es el nombre de cada columna de temp_datos. Entonces si en temp_tags me trae 5 registros quiere decir que en temp_datos vendrán 5 columnas respectivamente con datos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo inicialmente que relaciones tus tablas, para que estén asociadas una a otra a través del ID, y en tu tercera tabla ya tengas esa asociación, y así mismo puedas insertar los datos en esta y tengas el resultado que esperas

Comment: Cómo podría relacionar que por cada registro de temp_datos le pertenezcan todos los registros de una columna respectivamente de temp_datos.? :c

Comment: Pues no sé si esto te sirva:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabla_que_quieres` (
  `tabla_primerarelacion_id_primeratabla` int(X) NOT NULL,
  `tabla_segundarelacion_id_segundatabla` int(X) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tabla_primerarelacion_id_primeratabla`,`tabla_segundarelacion_id_segundatabla`),
  KEY `fk_tabla_que_quieres_segundatabla_idx` (`tabla_segundarelacion_id_segundatabla`),
  KEY `fk_tabla_que_quieres_primeratabla_idx` (`tabla_primerarelacion_id_primeratabla`)